# How to parse this string using regex or another technique?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string:

```
hello example >> hai man
```

How can I extract the "hai man" using Java regex or another technique?

Comment: @Tassos: ["The homework tag ... is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @subha, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex as:

```
String str    = "hello example >> hai man";
String result = str.replaceAll(".*>>\\s*(.*)", "$1");
```

Answer (score 2):

See run: http://www.ideone.com/cNMik

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "hello example >> hai man";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*>>\\s*(.*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

        if (m.matches())
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way is to play with character from String and its index.

For the `hello example >> hai man`  use

```
String str ="hello example >> hai man";
int startIndex = str.indexOf(">>");
String result = str.subString(startIndex+2,str.length());  //2 because >> two character
```

I think it clears up basic idea.

There are lots of tricks you can parse using

Another simpler way is :

```
     String str="hello example >> hai man";
     System.out.println(str.split(">>")[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1.4:

```
 String s="hello example >> hai man";
 String[] b=s.split(">>");
 System.out.println(b[1].trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //If I get a null value it means the stringToRetrieveFromParam does not contain stringToRetrieveParam.
        String returnVal = getStringIfExist("hai man", "hello example >> hai man");
        System.out.println(returnVal);

        returnVal = getStringIfExist("hai man", "hello example >> hai man is now in the middle!!!");
        System.out.println(returnVal);
    }

    /**Takes the example and make it more real-world like.
     * 
     * @param stringToRetrieveParam
     * @param stringToRetrieveFromParam
     * @return
     */
    public static String getStringIfExist(String stringToRetrieveParam,String stringToRetrieveFromParam){
        if(stringToRetrieveFromParam == null || stringToRetrieveParam == null){
            return null;
        }
        int index = stringToRetrieveFromParam.indexOf(stringToRetrieveParam);
        if(index > -1){
            return stringToRetrieveFromParam.substring(index,index + stringToRetrieveParam.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

what i understand that you wana eleminate this u can do some thing like

```
string myString = "hello example >> hai man";
string mySecondString = mystring.Replace("hai man", "");
```

You will get only `hello example >>`

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood the question.